# How to output string data on separate lines on Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, string, knitr, r-markdown

I am using a dataframe (called "Survey") from survey data in which the final question is an open comment box. Hence, my final vector in the dataframe consists of string data. I am attempting to create a report in R Markdown in which each comment (each row of that string vector) appears on a separate line in the outpout. My first attempt was to simply insert the variable name into a line of r code within my markdown window, as such:

`r Survey$Comments`

This resulted in the comments all appearing in one big chunk, with a comma separating each comment. I then attempted to use the "cat" function as follows:

`r cat(Survey$Comments, sep="\n")`

When I run this code in my regular R console window (not in R Markdown), it gives me the output I want (each comment on its own line), but does not work the same way when I run it in markdown. I'm at a loss as to how to get the output I need, and thought I'd turn to the broader community to see if anyone has any advice.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `writeLines`.

```
writeLines(c("Line1", "Line2", "Line3"))
Line1
Line2
Line3
```